# How can I find the most frequently recurring item in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

What would be the best approach to create the function `getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem()` below?

```
//should return "paragraph"
echo getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem(array('line', 'paragraph', 'paragraph'));

//should return "line"
echo getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem(array('wholeNumber', 'line', 'line', 'line'));

//should return null
echo getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem(array('wholeNumber', 'wholeNumber', 'paragraph', 'paragraph'));

//should return "wholeNumber"
echo getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem(array('wholeNumber', '', '', ''));

function getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem($items) {
    //...
}
```

## Answer:

Thanks Adam, here's my finished solution:
http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=396

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), and massage the output to your liking.

```
php> =array_count_values(array('wholeNumber', 'line', 'line', 'line'))
array(
  "wholeNumber" => 1,
  "line" => 3,
)
```

[`arsort($counts, SORT_NUMERIC)`](http://php.net/asort) will sort the `array_count_values()` output by most frequent first.

Comment: Mh, ksort() does sort by key and the keys are the words, so, wouldn´t it be better to use the sort() function to sort the words by occurence?

Comment: `sort()` will clobber the indexes, so you won't be able to identify the frequent words. I did pick the wrong function, though; I wanted `arsort()` to sort an associative array in reverse order, maintaining key/value pairs.

Comment: Now that makes more sense, +1 for your solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a candidate situation where you can apply [the linear-time majority vote algorithm](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/best-ideas/mjrty/index.html).

The link goes into a great explanation on how to apply this brilliantly simple algorithm.  Note that if you indeed want to return null to indicate a tie, this will require two passes over the data instead of one.

Comment: +0. OP isn't asking for majority but, rather, plurality.

Comment: @webbie: I had to look up the difference.  If anyone else is wondering, [Wikipedia has the answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurality_%28voting%29), as usual.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing an associative array of key and counter.

Answer (score 0):

Implode the array into a string separated by comma or space. Then use preg_match (http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to find the number of occurrences of a specified string. The pattern can be customized to exact match or occurrence match!